# ManagedPipelineHandler on List Request Hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-10

My system is  `C# MVC5 .NET` running on `Windows Server 2016` and `IIS 10`, it works pretty fine but it hangs after 10-15 requests in the modules that pass data via URL.

It only happens after it's deployed and I have to recycle the application pool every single time. I used `inetsrv>appcmd list requests /elapsed:30000` to see where it occurs, every time it shows something like this
[list requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTD1D.jpg)

Already uninstalled and installed `.NET` and tried the most common answer: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`, none worked, they are for older versions.

I'm stuck, does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use fail request tracing to find out where the request is hanging. We need find out the reason why your application hang when you have mulitple requests.  Details about how to troubleshoot this issue, you could refer to this [article](http://mvolo.com/troubleshoot-iis-hanging-requests/).

Comment: I went line by line and it just stopped working out of nowhere randomly, sometimes in the first query, sometimes with the second, and so on, it is not in a specific query. I tried FRT and nothing.

Comment: That indicates your code is badly written and hang under certain circumstance. Learn how to debug (or remote debug) with a debugger (Visual Studio for example), so that you can step into your own code and find out what's the culprit.

Comment: @LexLi That's what I did, It doesn't hang on a certain line, it just stops.

Comment: "Stopped" in which way? w3wp.exe crashed? Please do give meaning description.

Comment: Sorry if I can't explain it correctly, w3wp.exe didn't crash. This function has to get some data lists, I was debugging line by line, and in some random point, after 10-15 requests, it just stops debugging and hangs. As I said before, it only happens with data sent via URL.